# Creating a SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Making a query about delivery address. If delivery address is null use billing address. Im not sure how to make a column referring to as address. Using delivery address and billing address. This would need to be done with a union clause

Comment: Use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php).

Comment: Please show your table with all the columns. There is no way to determine the SQL without knowing what the table looks like.

Comment: your question is not clear. provide a table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: And since you say it would need to be done with a union clause, I'd be curious to understand why.

Comment: What is a "union clause" anyway? I know the union OPERATOR, never heard of a union CLAUSE.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle and SQL server:**

```
Select 
Case 
    When DeliveryAddress is NULL then BillingAddress
    Else BillingAddress
End "Address"
from tbl
```

Or in case of Oracle only,

```
Select COALESCE(DeliveryAddress, BillingAddress) "Address" from tbl
```

Comment: For SQL Server you need to use `is null` also and the `as` is optional.  So I'd suggest that the latter `case` could be used for both SQL Server and Oracle.